# How do i add an Edge to a graph which is a List<list<int>>?

Tags: c#, list, undirected-graph

I have a`List< List< int> > graph;`
I have used it for representing an undirected graph.
When i add a new edge `graph[u].Add[v];`, I am unable to itertate for a specific `graph[u]`.

Comment: You will need to post your actual code, nobody can help you on this little information.

Comment: @nvoigt isnt that my actual code huh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your graph is undirected, you probably want to indicate both that u is connected to v and that v is connected to u.

```
graph[u].Add(v);
graph[v].Add(u);
```

Then you can see the nodes connected to u by iterating graph[u].